# Images broken in forked heroku app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I followed [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/fork-app) tutorial on how to fork an existing app. Looks good except all the images in my new forked app are broken.

Is there an additional step I need to take to ensure they work? I feel like it's something to do with precompiling but not sure exactly what I need to do.

Comment: Where are those images? Are they hosted from your assets folder or 3rd parties servers like cloudinary?

Comment: assets/images/logo-red.png   and linking to it like <%= image_tag('logo-red.png', :class=>"img-responsive") %>

Comment: and the output html from the page is "/assets/logo-red-a07050d882e1dba431cef2130d39f929c611eaf8b0ec3c50db0742ddccb14d93.png" alt="Logo red a07050d882e1dba431cef2130d39f929c611eaf8b0ec3c50db0742ddccb14d93"   which is identical to my original (unforked app)

Comment: Hmmmm, did you redeploy to the new fork?

Comment: Yes, I made a few changes then redeployed